# Why is my Trim View greyed out in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I tried to change to CPU preview, also to unlock some of my frames, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Tech support is generally off-topic here. Maybe reach out to Adobe customer support. Could it be a bug? Maybe reset your preferences, update your graphic card driver. Sorry I can't help more. I'm still on CC 2018, and it doesn't have this feature, so it must be relatively new (and therefore potentially buggy)

Comment: It works in other files. So it is about the usage of the software.

Comment: My many brushes stored in Print.ai are disabling the feature, if I create a new document with the Print.ai  document profile, trim view still works, until I open the brushes tab, that has LOTS of brushes, cause they are stored in my print.ai. Is this some memory limit issue?

Comment: there's no way to tell to be honest, but it does sound like a possible bug. Just because it works in one document and not in another doesn't mean it isn't still a bug. Perhaps if you still want to trim it, do it the old fashioned way. Group all your artwork, draw a rectangle same size as the page, select both group, and rectangle, and do Object > Clipping Mask > Make.

Comment: Thanks, but the masking method is just trouble. It was easy to fix it, i saved all my brushes in an AI file, then deleted the Print.ai document profile, and it got recreated automatically at app restart, without my 300MB of brushes that was all stored in it.

Comment: It seems that the issue is caused by many (300 MB) brushes saved inside document profiles. Because when I open my new clean document profile, Print.ai, and I load the brushes into my brushes tab from a separate .ai file where I saved them, the Trim View works. Someone tested with 150 MB brushes and it still worked, depends on system memory maybe (I have 32 GB of RAM), anyway it seems that it's better to save the brushes into a separate AI file, not in the document profile.